# How to replace a line with a certain pattern in vi?

Tags: vi

I am trying to replace lines that contain the pattern `s#_decoded_block[` with `s#_decoded_block_`. The command I am using to do that is `%s/s\d\+_decoded_block\\[/s\d\+_decoded_block_/g`.

I expect to get `s#_decoded_block_` as substitutions but instead I am getting `sd+_decoded_block_`. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\d` and `+` are only meaningful in the search text, not in the replacement text.  If you want to capture what was matched and then use it in the replacement text, you need a match group:

```
%s/\(s\d+_decoded_block\)\[/\1_/
```

in this case I capured the whole thing you want to preserve so as not to have to retype it.